# stream count vs toList size

Tags: java, java-stream

Which is faster?

```
myCollection.stream().filter(somePredicate).count();
```

vs

```
myCollection.stream().filter(somePredicate).collect(Collectors.toList()).size();
```

Apparently, second seems to be slower. But wonder if there is any optimization done internally?

Comment: Is there any reason you think that the second *should* be faster? Or did you not expect that result? The second example clearly needs to do more, so sounds rather straightforward to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second snippet requires creating a `List` instance and adding all the elements of the `Stream` to it. Naturally that would be slower than just counting the number of elements of the `Stream`, which is what the first snippet does.